# lpfnWndProc Member function must be called

Tags: c++, windows, borland-c++

I Have a app that needs detect insertion new devices.
But i get a error on "wndClass.lpfnWndProc = reinterpret_cast(WndProcTest );" the error is "Member function must be called or its address taken".
I use Borland C++ builder 6.
Maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

My code AppMainForm.cpp:

```
bool TAppMainForm::InitWindowClass()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass;

    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndClass.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.hInstance = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetModuleHandle(0));
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(WndProcTest );
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(192,192,192));
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.hIconSm = wndClass.hIcon;

    if ( ! RegisterClassEx(&wndClass) )
    {
        //ErrorHandler(TEXT("RegisterClassEx"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

INT_PTR WINAPI TAppMainForm::WndProcTest(
        HWND hWnd,
        UINT message,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    // do something
}
```

Header File:

```
public: 
    bool InitWindowClass();
    INT_PTR WINAPI WndProcTest(
        HWND hWnd,
        UINT message,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam
    );
```

Comment: This is exactly what `reinterpret_cast` is not for. There's an underlying problem that member function pointers are completely different from function pointers because the former needs an object to operate on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you're trying to take the address of a C++ member function and assign it to a pointer to a C function, `lpfnWndProc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what's the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways to fix this:

1. Make the member function static
2. Don't use a member function
3. Declare the function static

   static INT_PTR WINAPI WndProcTest(....)
   {
   // do something
   }

   wndClass.lpfnWndProc = reinterpret_cast(InitWindowClass::WndProcTest );
4. Make WndProcTest an old fashioned C function (and remove it from your class):

   INT_PTR WINAPI WndProcTest(....)
   {
   // do something
   }